# How can I set a radio button as default?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

How can I set a radio button as default? I have already searched several threads and tried different methods but nothing seems to work.

```py
    #variable is a given string
    import tkinter as tk

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    a = tk.IntVar()
    a.set(1)

    tk.Label(win, text = "String").grid(row = 0, sticky = "w")
    tk.Label(win, text = "String").grid(row = 1, sticky = "w")
    e1 = tk.Entry(win)
    e1.insert(tk.END, variable)
    e1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    e2 = tk.Entry(win)
    e2.insert(tk.END, variable)
    e2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    tk.Label(win, text = "String").grid(row = 2, sticky = "w")
    start = tk.Radiobutton(win, text = "String", variable = a, value = 1, command = function1)
    start.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    start.invoke()
    tk.Radiobutton(win, text = "String", variable = a, value = 2, command = function2).grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    tk.Radiobutton(frame, text = "String", variable = a, value = 3, command = function3).grid(row = 2, column = 3)
```

Comment: does calling it with `state="Active"` work?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already tried it and unfortunately, it does not.

Comment: maybe you mean set focus on widget ? ie. `start.focus()`

Comment: Your code won't run, it's missing several variables and functions. Why do you think it doesn't work? When I fix all of the obvious problems in your code, when it starts up one of the radiobuttons is selected.

Comment: @furas thanks for the advice but I was looking for a possibility to select a button by default (it needs to be selected/filled with a dot). Also thanks to you, Bryan, I just wanted to provide the structure and keep it simple. For this occasion, it should not be important which effect the functions have in general. I am still on the search for a solution. The root (root = tk.Tk()) is an element in the calling function.

Comment: If the functions aren't important, then don't configure the widgets to call functions which don't exist. If you say something doesn't work, and don't provide code to prove it, it's hard for us to help.

Comment: to set button selected (set "dot") you have to use `a = tk.IntVar(vlaue=1)` or `a.set(1)`. You already have second command. If it doesn't work then you have problem in rest of  code. You may use two variables with the same name. Or maybe you have two `Tk()` and two `mainloop()`. Or maybe it is problem only on your system. On Linux when I add to your code needed command (ie. `mainloop()) then it run correctly. Create minimal working code with your problem so we could run it and see if problem exists on our computers.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I forgot to add mainloop at the end!

Answer (score 1):

All radiobuttons in a group should share the same variable, and each should have a unique value. You simply need to set the value of the variable to the value from one of the radiobuttons.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.IntVar(value=1)

for value in range(10):
    rb = tk.Radiobutton(root, text=str(value), variable=var, value=value)
    rb.pack(side="top")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, it is not working in my case.

Comment: @cspecial: then please provide a complete [mcve]. We can't run the code you posted, and when I fixed all of the problems, your code worked fine.